# Allow Phone Call android; npm run cordova-build-ios; npm run cordova-build-android; whatsapp

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, npm

Android Manifest says this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

CALL_PHONE
Allows an application to initiate a phone call without going through the Dialer user interface for the user to confirm the call.

Can I add it to my config.xml-file unter the tag.

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

How can I access it? I appreciate:

```
telephone.call('110')
```

Can I call another app with following command:

```
app.show('com.yahoo.mailapp')
```

How can I access the camera with javascript? I appreciate:

```
camerapicture = camera.fetch()
```

How can I make touch and click-Actions with my phone? I appreciate:

```
v-on:touch and v-on:click
```

Do I need to add another plugin with

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device-orientation
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device-motion
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-battery-status
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device

best practicessudo npm install -g cordovaC:>npm install -g cordovacordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorldcd hellocordova platform add androidcordova platform rm androidcordova buildcordova build ioscordova emulate androidcordova run androidcordova-plugin-statusbarcordova plugin add cordova-plugin-devicecom.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner$ cordova requirementsRequirements check results for android:Java JDK: installed .Android SDK: InstalledAndroid target: installed android-19,android-21,android-22,android-3,Google Inc.:Google APIs:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs (x86 System Image):19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23Gradle: installedRequirements check results for ios:Apple OS X: not installedCordova tooling for iOS requires Apple OS XError: Some of requirements check failed$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-cameraFetching plugin "cordova-plugin-camera@~2.1.0" via npmInstalling "cordova-plugin-camera" for androidInstalling "cordova-plugin-camera" for ios$ cordova plugin ls
cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.0 "Camera"cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
$ cordova platform update android --save$ cordova platform update ios --save

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61136923/cordova-build-ios-app-on-windows-os-npm-run-cordova-build-ios

Comment: If you have some questions, why I would implement this way, just call me, I love you!!!